# How can I convert base64 binary data into wkb - well known binary?

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis

I am stuck with conversion of base 64 binary converted using shptosql into sql server. now I want to convert the data into postgres, which supports wkb- well known binary. How can I convert base64 bytes into suppoorted format which is well known binary in java? I have decoded base64 but wkb is still far from my point.

1. Part 1 : Read XML Part (Done)
2. Part 2 : Extract Binary data Part (Done)
3. Part 3 : Convert into wkb (Left)
4. Part 4 : Store wkb in postgresSQL

   ```
   File f = new File(request.getRealPath("/")+"themes\\ProfileImages\\temp.xml");
   ArrayList<byte[]> byteArray = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
   if(f.exists()){
       List<String> list = geoserver.getShapes(f);
       for(String s : list){
           BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
           byte[] decodedBytes=null;
           try {
               decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(s);
               byteArray.add(decodedBytes);

               //Here I want to convert bytes to wkb format and want to save in postgres

           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }   
       }

       List<String> objects =geoserver.getObjectIds(f);
       List<ShapeFile> shapes = new ArrayList<ShapeFile>();
       for(int i=0;i<byteArray.size();i++){
           try {
               shapes.add(new ShapeFile(objects.get(i), byteArray.get(i),IOUtils.toString(byteArray.get(i))));
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   ```

Part 3 is left for me.

Can someone please tell me how and using which libraries I can do that?

Comment: [Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)?

Comment: It is bytes encoded with base64

Comment: Base64 is not an encoding - it is a format.

Comment: Then how can I achieve my target?

Comment: Postgres uses custom data type which is geometry and SQL server uses bytes how to bridge them now?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Base 64 is a binary-to-text encoding, not a format.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64